# Comparing the return values of .getClass() and .class

Tags: java, spring-boot, equals

I'm trying to design some micro services using SpringBoot.

I have a problem when comparing (what seemed to me) same values and always getting an output of `false`. This is the method that should compare the 2 values:

```
@Override
public boolean accepts(Event event) {
    System.err.println("In the accepts method of FlightResponsePipelineProcessor");
    System.err.println(event.getValue().getClass());
    System.err.println(FlightResponse.class);
    System.err.println(event.getValue().getClass().equals(FlightResponse.class));
    return event.getValue().getClass().equals(FlightResponse.class);
}
```

When the method is executed, I get this in the console:

```
In the accepts method of FlightResponsePipelineProcessor
class avro.schemas.v1.FlightResponse
class avro.schemas.v1.FlightResponse
false
```

Does anyone know why? I assume that I misunderstood what .getClass() and .class return, but it seemed the same in the console.

Comment: when comparing classes, you can use the  == operator. where/how do you print that 'false'?

Comment: This is the line that gives the false value: System.err.println(event.getValue().getClass().equals(FlightResponse.class));

Comment: Will try the == thing and let you know if it works!

Comment: Are they perhaps loaded by different class loaders? (I know nothing about spring boot) That's one reason why two `Class` objects representing the same class would not be equal by `equals` or `==`.

Comment: This question might provide some more insight: [Comparing two classes by its types or class names](//stackoverflow.com/q/10465253)

Comment: or, perhaps, do you have two libraries, which contain different files with identical path and name? don't know if that can cause issues, but still ..

Comment: @Stultuske unfortunately, I get a `false` even with the `==`

Comment: @Sweeper I'm not completely sure how to check that, but will look into it.

Comment: @Cydonia you could call `Class.getClassLoader()` and print them out. That way you can easily see if they have been loaded by the same class loader

Comment: `FlightResponse.class class loader: org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@2d989b2b
event.getValue().getClass() class loader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@277050dc` So they are different after all, nice catch!